# What exactly is LLDB in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, lldb, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to understand what exactly is `LLDB` in Android Studio.

I am new to Android Studio and it's a bit puzzling as to if I should install this on an `AMD` system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[LLDB](https://lldb.llvm.org/) is a native debugger; nothing to worry about unless you use the `NDK`.

Current `AMD` `CPU` work fine, while using `KVM` or `WHPX` for the virtualization.